# Using java annotation with dynamic parameter

Tags: java, datasource, cdi, jndi

What I'm trying to achieve is have a `@Resource` with a dynamic `name` parameter. Specifically, I want to inject a `DataSource` object using `@Resource(name = "{JNDI_NAME_PARAM}")` because we can have many datasources configured in an application server, and the datasource used by the application is defined in an .xml or .config file. Since I do not know the name of the datasource during compile time I need to be able to get it at runtime. Right now I'm injecting a custom `@ApplicationScoped` bean which creates a datasource in its `@PostConstruct` method using `InitialContext().lookup()`. However I'm curious (mostly because it is more elegant) as to how I could achieve injection using the `@Resource` annotation.

I COULD create a custom default JNDI name in the app server and change the datasource it points to when needed but this can't work with more than one deployment and many times we have the application deployed twice, once in a test database and once in a production database so having the JNDI point at two different datasources at the same time.

Comment: Well, to answer the "question" in your title: you absolutely cannot have an annotation value that is not fixed at compile time. But that doesn't mean that whatever you're using doesn't have a non-annotation way to inject things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Method based injection.
It requires the setter method (setMyDB).

```
public class Test {

  public javax.sql.DataSource myDB;

  @Resource(name="student")
  private void setMyDB(javax.sql.DataSource ds) {
      myDB = ds;
  }
}
```

If the names are known, we can have multiple resources under

```
@Resources({

 @Resource(your type)
 @Resource(your type)
})
```

Comment: I didn't really get it. Are your code snippets part of the solution or two different ways to achieve this? Also, the names are unknown and not predefined. It's not like I have to choose from a list of JNDI names and I don't know which one to choose. The JNDI name is defined by our tech guy responsible for installing the application on the client's server. What he does is unpackage the `.war`, change the `<env-entry>` on the `web.xml` and repackage it. Also creating a wrapper class isn't really a solution since i've already implemented something like that. I could even a `@Produces` annotation.

Comment: They're different ways. You can try another way, by having the static variable, assigning the passed value to this static variable and this variable can be used at the place of @Resource(name=static_variable).

Comment: I tried the variable method but it has to be `final` otherwise it won't compile